# Application window getting hide

Tags: windows, mfc, taskbar

I have done multi threaded MFC application. App is running fine, but after some time PC window gets logged off with the given password to log in the PC. My application does not appear anywhere but process is running.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Without a code snippet provided I can only give theoretical suggestions. Please check the termination or disposal of your threads upon exiting the App. I recommend this article on thread termination:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s21xzfe.aspx

Comment: I hope UI thread is running. Also verified.

Comment: Window just getting hide probably he received some message i didn't handled or wrongly handled i think.

Comment: It's not clear what is happening when the "PC window gets logged off". So my guess is that the window is closed in a manner that does not allow the program to stop the threads and/or exit the program normally. You might be able to add code to catch the event of being closed.

Comment: Use remote debugging. Should be easy to find out, what happens. Also Spy++ can help, if a special Windows message causes this.

Comment: @user34660 I didn't mean to shot down my PC. Just lack ( windows+L) the screen.

Comment: Somehow my application getting WM_SHOWWINDOW this message. I can't able to debug, it's receives from where. Please any buddy know how to solve this.

Comment: Since your application is getting a WM_SHOWWINDOW message your message loop is still executing. Something is preventing the window from closing properly.